# Detecting Special Key Presses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box and want to adjust the value when a key is pressed.

```
'keypress .comment-input': 'onCommentInputKeyBlur',
```

When a key is pressed, a class is added to the html element to reflect the changes.

```
      onCommentInputKeyBlur: function(ev) {
        var $form = $('#comment-submit');
        if (ev.which) {
            $form.addClass('focused');
        } else if (!$(ev.currentTarget).val()) {
            $form.removeClass('focused');
        }
    },
```

However, this doesn't detect special keys being pressed (ie when a user presses ctrl+v for a paste, it's not detected and the formatting is therefore wrong).

Using keyup and keydown halfway solve the problem, but formatting is wrong for a brief second:

Keydown -> the value isn't supposed to change until an actual value is entered through a keypress, but it changes right when **ctrl** is hit instead of waiting for the second key

Keyup -> new value is briefly pasted over the previous one while waiting for the key to actually be released.

Is there a better way to about solving this? Ideally, I would like to detect if the key entered does actually produce a value and is not simply a special key.

Comment: the `keypress` event is fired whenever a key is pressed. Are you asking how to determine whether the user pressed a valid key?

Comment: The keypress event isn't registering when control (or similar special key) is pressed. keyup and keydown recognize it, however.

Comment: This will tell you how different browsers respond to various key events: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html. You're right - it looks like `ctrl` doesn't fire the keypress event.

Comment: Can you provide more code showing what you tried? I'm still not sure what specific events you're trying to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the onchange event. It is fairly well supported and may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the ultimate goal of this functionality? perhaps there is a better approach.

If you insist on doing this via keypress event, then you can simply check event.keyCode and filter out the few keycodes that dont change anything, such as shift, control, alt.